# Howto query and change network namespace on linux?

Tags: linux, network-namespace

I was wondering if there is a way to

1. Query the network namespace the current shell is in
2. Change the current network namespace of the current shell

I know I can do things like

```
sudo ip netns exec <namespace_name> <some command>
```

to execute a certain command in a certain network namespace, but I was thinking of something like

```
:~$ sudo query_current_namespace
some_namespace
:~$ sudo change_current_namespace_to other_namespace
:~$ sudo query_current_namespace
other_namespac
:~$ dothings in newnamespace
```

Just like changerooting into into some subdir, so I won't have to prefix every command with the `sudo ip netns exec <namespace>` thingy.

Searching the net it looks like I would have to write my own littel C Program, like suggested [in this blog post](https://eos.aristanetworks.com/2011/06/linux-namespaces-at-arista/). Is there allready a "standard" tool for this?

**Edit:** I just found that I could do

```
sudo ip netns exec <namespace> bash
```

which will give me a root shell in a new namespace. So almost there, but how do I query the current namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the man page:

```
   ip netns identify PID - Report network namespaces names for process
       This command walks through /var/run/netns and finds all the network
       namespace names for network namespace of the specified process.
```

So you would do something like:

```
ip netns identify $$
```

Comment: On what kind of system have you found this man page? At least on ubuntu 12.04 and fedora 18, the option `identify` is not present. The man page does not list it and the command does not recocnise it.

Comment: It's on my Fedora 19 system.

Comment: I see, so its brand spankin new ;) Still, I am amazed that it takes that long (since linux 2.6.29) for such a cool feature to make it into admin tools.